# Get database creation timestamp from PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to get a date and time of when a particular database was created in Postgresql?

The `\list` command does not provide a timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built-in method to do so, but [there are workarounds](http://raghavt.blogspot.com.au/2011/09/how-to-get-database-creation-time-in.html).

Note however that [even `PG_VERSION` changes when the server is updated to a new major version](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20060920165851.38074.qmail@web58305.mail.re3.yahoo.com).

So the only reliable way to store a creation date is to make a one-row table with the date in it.

If this feature is important to your application you could consider funding its development. I think it'd be pretty trivial to implement.